# AVPlayerLayer flashes black on AVPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with:)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

I have an `AVPlayer` object that I am using to play a video. When the user taps a button, the video is swapped out for a different video, which continues playing. Just using `replaceCurrentItem(with:)` is resulting in a few tenths of a second of a black frame appearing on my `AVPlayerLayer` that is displaying the video content.

I have code in place to render an image at the current frame before the `AVPlayerItem` is swapped out, to bridge the gap before the new `AVPlayerItem` has a frame ready to display, but the black frame is blocking this image from view. Is there any way to control what the `AVPlayerLayer` will render before it has actual video data to display?

Alternatively, is there a way to be notified that the `AVPlayerLayer` (or the `AVPlayerItem` has actually begun displaying video data? Observing for when the state of the item becomes `.readyToPlay` triggers too early, hiding the image at that point still leaves the black frame visible.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same flash problem with my macOS app. I resolved it by renewing `AVPlayerLayer` each time I play a new file.

I have an `AVPlayer` subclass. The function below removes `AVPlayerLayer` from its super layer and add a new layer to the view.

```swift
class MyVideoPlayer: AVPlayer {

    func addLayer(view: NSView) {
        view.layer!.sublayers?
            .filter { $0 is AVPlayerLayer }
            .forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        let layer = AVPlayerLayer.init(player: self)
        layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resize
        layer.frame = view.bounds
        view.layer!.addSublayer(layer)
    }

}
```

In my `ViewController`, I call this before I play a video content.

```swift
myVideoPlayer.addLayer(view: self.view)
```